# Change barStyle of UITabBar during runtime

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar

I have an app with a few tabs in a tab bar, where I would like to make one of them darker when active. Kinda like the iTunes app, when you go to the Movies-section.

But it seems like I can't change the `barStyle` when the tabbar was added? Is there some limitation I don't know about?

This is the code I'm using:

```
[self.tabbar setBarStyle:[TiUtils intValue:value]];
```

Where the `TiUtils` return either `1` (for black) or `0` (for default).

Comment: I am assuming you are working with `iOS7.0` because in iOS 7 you don't get darker selection, though you can always customize your tabbar.

Comment: I am working with iOS7. What I meant was changing the barStyle-property on the whole UITabBar, to get UIBarStyleBlack.